# Linq query not returning any data to the Datagridview (Possible failure on linq query) C#

Tags: c#, mysql, linq

Please can someone help? I need to return a table on Extn_In_Call_Records = Extn_Number and if either side does not match still return a value just like a SQL Full Outer join. I have spent hours looking at this and had some help but cant get it to work!! The Datatables is being populated from MYSQL. Any help woud be great. I would also like to say I am very new to LINQ and C# I am not getting any errors on the query but it is not returning anything to the gridview?

These are the table that are being populated by the MySQL data. I have put the column names as comments under the datatables.

```
   DataTable physextns = new DataTable(); 
   extnlkp.Fill(physextns);
   //Table Format Below
   //("Company_Name")
   //("Phys_Switch_Name")
   //("Extn_Number")

    DataTable callrecdt = new DataTable();
    callrec.Fill(callrecdt);
    //Table Format Below
    //("Switch_Name");
    //("Extn_In_Call_Records");
    //("Total_Calls");
    //("Talk_Time");
    //("Total_Cost");

        try
         {

            //Full Result

             var defaultPhysex = new { };

             var left =from callrc in callrecdt.AsEnumerable()
                        join physex in physextns.AsEnumerable()
                          on callrc["Extn_In_Call_Records"] equals physex["Extn_Number"]
                        into temp
                        from physex in temp.DefaultIfEmpty()
                        select new
                        {
                        Extn_In_Call_Records = ("Extn_In_Call_Records"),
                        Total_Calls = ("Total_Calls"),
                        Extn_Number = ("Extn_Number"),
                        Phys_Switch_Name = ("Phys_Switch_Name"),               
                         };

             var right = from physex in physextns.AsEnumerable()
                         join callrc in callrecdt.AsEnumerable()
                         on physex["Extn_Number"] equals callrc["Extn_In_Call_Records"]
                         into temp
                         from physex1 in temp.DefaultIfEmpty(defaultPhysex)
                         select new
                         {
                            Extn_In_Call_Records = ("Extn_In_Call_Records"),
                            Total_Calls = ("Total_Calls"),
                            Extn_Number = ("Extn_Number"),
                            Phys_Switch_Name = ("Phys_Switch_Name"),
                         };

             var union = left.Union(right);
             fullresult.DataSource = union;  //fullresult is the datatable I am populating
```

Result to see

```
Extn_In_Call_Records    Total_Calls   Extn_Number      Phys_Switch_Name
null                    20                0                Hospital
null                    310               1                Hospital
4                       132               4                Hospital
2004                    null                null           Hospital
2006                    2               2006           Hospital
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see an obvious problem with your code. Your call to `Union` should return all common records between the two sets.

You didn't say what platform you're programming for, so I tried it in a `WinForms` `DataGridView`. An `IEnumerable` (the type returned by `Union`) doesn't seem to bind.

Try adding a `ToList()` at the end.

```
fullresult.DataSource = union.ToList();
```